# Adding an image before <h:link> value

Tags: jsf

Currently I am using **h:graphicImage** inside **h:link** and it adds an image after the text.

```
<h:link outcome="some outcome" value="some text">
    <h:graphicImage value="image.png" />
</h:link>
```

It produces an output like **some text(image.png)** what I want is to achieve like this **(image.png)some text** Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `value` attribute and put the text directly after the image like this :

```
<h:link outcome="some outcome">
    <h:graphicImage value="image.png" />
    some text
</h:link>
```